# Classification with Neural networks

Tags: java, random, neural-network, classification

I am working on big data classification. I have tested many classifiers on big datasets. At the end, I have noticed that two classifiers achieved the best results but with long running time (Bagging & Random Tree).
My question is:
I want to modify Random Tree to use neural networks, but I want to know before I wast a lot of time on programming for nothing, which type of neural networks should I use for improving the classifier results and running time?

- Deep learning
- backpropagation
- stochastic gradient descent
- or a combination between them

=======

Thanks in advance for everyone in StackOverflow they are the best

Comment: What you were counting there is actually all different parts. So getting your point is a bit hard... Backpropagation for example is using (stoachastic) gradient descent to train a neural network, which is part of deep learning ^^

Comment: I think you are mixing points. A neural network is considered as Deep Learning when you start to have an important number of hidden layer (that's why we call it deep, for example 19 for the existing VGG19). BackPropagation is a process used to train a neural network. You propagate the error backward and adjust weight. SGD is one of the way to do the backpropagation, there is several more. I think you are mining with Standard NN, Convolutionnal NN, Recurrent NN, ... but this depend to your application

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nicolas & Luftbaum for answering my question. this was very helpfull.